# Loading a plugin's js file from functions.php

Tags: plugins, functions

I'm trying to change the way a plugin register's its own js file from this:

```
function gpvd_enqueue_styles_admin() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'gpvb-admin-styles',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/admin.css',
        array(),
        '',
        'all'
    );
    wp_register_script(
        'gpvb-admin-scripts',
        plugins_url( 'js/block.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor' ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/block.js' ),
        false
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gpvb-admin-scripts' );
}
```

and change the `false` to a `true`.

So I put this in my `functions.php` file:

```
function sh_child_enqueue_styles_admin() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'gpvb-admin-styles',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/admin.css',
        array(),
        '',
        'all'
    );
    wp_register_script(
        'gpvb-admin-scripts',
        plugins_url( 'js/block.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor' ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/block.js' ),
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gpvb-admin-scripts' );
}

remove_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'gpvb_enqueue_styles_admin');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sh_child_enqueue_styles_admin');
```

However, it can't find the plugin's js file because of `__FILE__`. Do I have to hard code the path in there or is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: So you're trying to change an enqueued script to load in the footer instead of the header?

Comment: Does this matter, particularly if it's an admin script? I can't imagine it makes much difference to the page load time or could possibly break anything.

Comment: The way it currently loads conflicts with the customization js of a theme I'm using:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/js-conflict-with-shapely-theme/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels slightly fragile, but you can probably just do:

```
wp_scripts()->add_data( 'gpvb-admin-scripts', 'group', 1 );
```

in a low-priority admin_enqueue_scripts hook, since that's what [wp_register_script does with the $is_footer flag](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.3.1/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L154). However this risks a future version of WordPress changing how this is saved internally (although it's been stable for 5+ years).

Alternatively you could query for the existing entry and use [the dependency properties](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_wp_dependency/) to overwrite the existing dependency entry using wp_register_script again:

```
$existing_script = wp_scripts()->query( 'gpvb-admin-scripts' );
if ( $existing_script ) {
    // Overwrite existing registration
    wp_deregister_script( $existing_script->handle ); 
    wp_register_script( $existing_script->handle,
                        $existing_script->src,
                        $existing_script->deps,
                        $existing_script->ver,
                        true );
}
```

ditto in a low-priority admin_enqueue_scripts hook.

Comment: I got it working. However, the only way I could get it to work was by leaving the 'false' alone and not changing it to 'true.' There has got to be some weird voodoo going on with the customization js.